# SFTP batch file to copy from remote to local

Tags: shell, unix, sftp, batch-processing, vsftpd

I have some files in remote server. I need to copy those file from remote server to my local server.

```
Source path : pABCDWPPP@170.20.100.10:/SRC_path (dummy server name)
Target path : /data/TGT_path
```

i have tried this...

```
infa@vm-ppp-50:/data/TGT_path$ sftp -oPort=10000 pABCDWPPP@170.20.100.10:/SRC_path
SSH Server supporting SFTP and SCP
Connected to 170.20.100.10.
Changing to: /SRC_path
sftp> ls -l
-rw-------   1 200      100            17 Dec 04 15:15 test-20191204-1572921093125.csv
-rw-------   1 200      100           592 Dec 02 10:59 test-20191125-1574678916536.csv
-rw-------   1 200      100             9 Dec 04 15:15 t-20191204-1575253807720.csv
-rw-------   1 200      100            15 Dec 04 15:15 test-20191204-1575253807720.csv
-rw-------   1 200      100            17 Dec 04 15:16 test-20191204-1575426603349.csv
sftp> bye
```

I have to create a batch script which should copy those file from source path to target path.

file names can be different. but it has some patterns which i can use as a variable.

This is the syntax that can be used in the script:

```
sftp -oPort=10000 ${USERID}@170.20.100.10:${MAILBOXPATH} <<EOF
mget ${FILE}
bye
EOF
```

Can anyone help me to create the script file which can copy those file(s) in batch mode everyday.
I have to execute the script in unix.

Answer (score 1):

schedule a cron job to execute your script, please see [scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/)

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But i my requirement is to create sftp script with mentioned details.

Comment: @goldenbutter But you already have the SFTP script, don't you?

Comment: actually this script is harcoded for one file... i have multiple files ... i need some for loop or batch file mode to check first if the files are present, then copy files as per pattern in my local.....

Comment: That's quite vague. Please edit your question with details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SFTP, I would use rsync which is well adapted for this task:

```
#!/bin/bash
# backup.sh
rsync --modify-window=5 -rltzuv --delete [REMOTE_SERVER@REMOTE_DIR] [LOCAL_SERVER@LOCAL_DIR]
```

Then you can run a cron job as follows:

```
crontab crontab.sh
```

where:

```
# content of crontab.sh (scheduled to run everyday at 2am)
0 2 * * * /bin/sh /path/to/backup.sh
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But i my requirement is to create sftp script with mentioned details.

Comment: OK, no problem. At least, the cron job might be used in this case.